# RREF of a matrix in MatLab

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have questions about manually RREF'ing a given matrix. So I went through it partially but I can't figure out where to go from here. Thanks!

```
 M = [1 0 2 1 18; 
     0 -3 -2 0 -8; 
     -2 -3 0 0 -41; 
     1 0 -1 1 16];
 M2=M;
 M2(3,:) = M2(3,:)+(2*M2(1,:));
 M2(4,:) = M2(4,:)-M2(1,:);
 M3 = M2;
 M3(3,:) = M3(3,:)+M3(2,:);
 M3(3,:) = M3(3,:)-M3(2,:);
 M3(3,:) = M3(3,:)-M3(2,:);
 M3(2,:) = (-1/3)*M3(2,:)
```

end I end up with

```
[1 0 2 1 18; 
0 1 .6667 0 2.6667; 
0 0 6 2 3; 
0 0 -3 0 -2]
```

Comment: Are you interested only in the final result or in the algorithm getting you there? If it's the latter, then this question is better suited for [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Did you find any of the answers below helpful?

Answer (score 0):

To pick up where you left:

```
x = [1 0 2 1 18; 0 1 .6667 0 2.6667; 0 0 6 2 3; 0 0 -3 0 -2];
x(3,:) = x(3,:) / 6;

x(1,:) = x(1,:) - 2 * x(3,:);
x(2,:) = x(2,:) - 2/3 * x(3,:);
x(4,:) = x(4,:) + 3 * x(3,:);

x(1,:) = x(1,:) - 1/3 * x(4,:);
x(2,:) = x(2,:) + 2/9 * x(4,:);
x(3,:) = x(3,:) - 1/3 * x(4,:);
```

And similar to `rref(x)` this produces:

```
x =

    1.0000         0         0    0.0000   17.1667
         0    1.0000    0.0000         0    2.2223
         0         0    1.0000         0    0.6667
         0         0         0    1.0000   -0.5000
```

This is a convenient way to do it if you want to know all steps in between, but obviously using the `rref` function is typically better at finding the reduced row echelon form.

Note that the rounding issue would not occur if you do all the steps in matlab rather then copying values like `.6667`.